# Find the values of parameter a so that matrices A and B

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

Find  the values of parameter a so that matrices $A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 &4-a-a^2 \\ 
2 & -1
\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix}
-a-1 &3 \\ 
3 & -5
\end{pmatrix}$  may represent the same bilinear form in different bases.

As I know, if matrix of bilinear form is nonsingular with respect to some basis, it's also nonsingular in any basis. S0, we have
 det(A) and det(B) are nonzero. Is it enough condition?

Comment: No. Hint: think about change of basis.

Comment: I have already thought about it. A=S^t*B*S . So what?

Answer (score 2):

No, it isn't a sufficient condition.

First of all, $A$ has to be symmetric.

Therefore, $a$ is solution of the quadratic equation $a^2+a-2=0$ giving

$$a=1 \ \ \text{or} \ \ a=-2$$

As $\det(A)=-1-4 < 0$, it is compulsory that $\det(B)<0$ as well.

This is only possible with

> $$a=-2 \ \ \text{giving} \ \ \det(B)=-14$$

As, with this choice of $a$, we have the same (positive) sign for the two upper left entries : $A_{11} >0$ and $B_{11} > 0$, we are sure that $A$ and $B$ are equivalent, because their leading principal minors have the same signs ([Sylvester law of inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia)).

One can look for matrix $S$ such that $S^TBS=A$ ; one finds, using a computer :

$$S=\begin{pmatrix} \sqrt{70} - 2 \sqrt{13} - 3 \sqrt{910}/14 + 6& \sqrt{13} - 3\\
                             \sqrt{910}/14 - 2&            1\end{pmatrix}$$ 
 (no comments !)

Comment: Why does A has to be symmetric?

Comment: @Levon Minasian. Because the second matrix is symmetric. Indeed, if they represent the same quadratic form wrt to 2 different bases, one has (PX)^TA(PY)=XBY for a certain basis change represented by matrix $P$. Now transpose LHS and RHS : you will see, by specializing $X$ and $Y$ that it is not possible that $A$ is not symmetric.