# When does matrices represent the same bilinear form

Tags: matrices, bilinear-form, change-of-basis

Here is the task I was recently asked to solve:

*At what value of the paramter $a$ matrices*

\begin{equation*}
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 4-a-a^2 \\
2 &  -1\\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

*and*
\begin{equation*}
B = 
\begin{pmatrix}
-a-1 & 3 \\
3 &  -5\\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

*can be the matrices of a same bilinear form $V \times V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ in different bases?*

I know that if the matrices $A$ and $B$ represent the same bilinear form then
$$\exists \space S: A=S^TBS (1)$$

But what am I supposed to do next? Is it possible to solve equation $(1)$ for $S$?

I found the same post here: [Find the values of parameter a so that matrices A and B](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3562671/find-the-values-of-parameter-a-so-that-matrices-a-and-b)  - But there is no reasonable answer(why does $A$ has to be symmetric?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can notice that B is symmetric while A isn’t for every a. When you impose the condition on symmetry (you find the 2 values of a for wich A is symmetric) you can use spectral theory to determine wether or not they represent the same bilinear form. Obviously I consider that both are expressed in canonical bases.

Comment: Good job, bruh! Now I got it!

Answer (score 0):

Given two bases for the same vector space, there exist a matrix, S, that transforms the vectors in one basis to the basis in the other basis.  Then a matrix, A, in one basis is the same as the basis $SAS^{-1}$ in the other.